# node_modules/.bin/react-native run-android --no-packager' (error code 101) (error code 303)

Tags: android, react-native

I am not able to solve the above error when running Android build by debug config or by command npx react-native run-android.

I have checked and Configured the ANDROID_HOME environment variable as well but no luck.

I have also gone through the react-native official instruction for setup
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

I got the below error in the OUTPUT window.
[Error] Error: Error while executing command '/Users/apple/Desktop/xxxxxxxxx/node_modules/.bin/react-native run-android --no-packager' (error code 101)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1169#issuecomment-558188376)), or define the `sdk.dir` variable in your project's `android/local.properties` file.